# Gtkmm - change minimum size of Window

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm, gdk

I try to change the minimum size of an Gtk::Window. It should be possible to shrink the window to a smaller size then the biggest container in it to a specific size.

I try several approaches you can see below. Nothing shows any effect. The minimum always defined by the image size. What did I do wrong?

**main.cpp**

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include <gtkmm.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
  Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> app =
    Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "org.gtkmm.example");

  MainWindow mainWindow;
  return app->run(mainWindow);
}
```

**MainWindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H_INCLUDED
#define MAINWINDOW_H_INCLUDED

#include <gtkmm.h>
#include <gdkmm.h>

class MainWindow : public Gtk::Window
{
  public:
    MainWindow();
  private:
    Gtk::Image   m_Image;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H_INCLUDED
```

**MainWindow.cpp**

```
#include "MainWindow.h"

#define APPROACH_05

MainWindow::MainWindow() :
  m_Image( "image.png" )
{
  this->set_border_width(0);

#ifdef APPROACH_01
  this->add(m_Image);
  m_Image.set_size_request(5,5);
#endif // APPROACH_01

#ifdef APPROACH_02
  this->add(m_Image);
  this->set_size_request(5,5);
#endif // APPROACH_02

#ifdef APPROACH_03
  this->add(m_Image);
  Gtk::Allocation allocation = m_Image.get_allocation();
  allocation.set_width(5);
  allocation.set_height(5);
  m_Image.set_allocation(allocation);
#endif // APPROACH_03

#ifdef APPROACH_04
  this->add(m_Image);
  Gtk::Allocation allocation = this->get_allocation();
  allocation.set_width(5);
  allocation.set_height(5);
  this->set_allocation(allocation);
#endif // APPROACH_04

#ifdef APPROACH_05
  this->add(m_Image);
  Gdk::Geometry geom = {
    .min_width   = 5,
    .min_height  = 5,
  };
  Gtk::Window::set_geometry_hints(*this,geom,Gdk::HINT_MIN_SIZE);
#endif // APPROACH_05

  this->show_all_children();
}
```

*compiled with:*

```
g++ main.cpp MainWindow.cpp `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs` -o prog
```

---

@ptomato Thanks for your response. I have tried it this way:

```
#ifdef APPROACH_06
  this->add(m_ScrolledWindow);
  m_ScrolledWindow.set_border_width(0);
  m_ScrolledWindow.set_policy(Gtk::POLICY_NEVER,Gtk::POLICY_ALWAYS);
  m_ScrolledWindow.add(m_Image);
#endif // APPROACH_06
```

Now I can resize the window vertically, but I see the vertical scrollbar. If I set the policy to `POLICY_NEVER` like in the horizontal axis the window width is limited to the image width. Additionally the size of the slider limits the height too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to shrink the window down to a smaller size than the image inside it, then you need to put the image inside of a `Gtk::ScrolledWindow` before adding it to the window. Without scrolling, then the image wouldn't know what part of itself to render when you made the window smaller than the image.

Answer (score 1):

There is an approach to add a layer between the window and its contents, made of a custom container that lies to the parent window about its preferred size.

Here is my overridden [GtkFixed](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFixed.html) that solves exactly the same problem:

*reckless_fixed.h*

```
#ifndef __RECKLESS_FIXED_H__
#define __RECKLESS_FIXED_H__

#ifndef NO_INCLUDE_WITHIN_HEADERS
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#endif

#define RECKLESS_FIXED_TYPE                  (reckless_fixed_get_type ())
#define RECKLESS_FIXED(obj)                  (G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE_CAST ((obj), RECKLESS_FIXED_TYPE, RecklessFixed))
#define RECKLESS_FIXED_CLASS(klass)          (G_TYPE_CHECK_CLASS_CAST  ((klass), RECKLESS_FIXED_TYPE, RecklessFixedClass))
#define IS_RECKLESS_FIXED(obj)               (G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE_TYPE ((obj), RECKLESS_FIXED_TYPE))
#define IS_RECKLESS_FIXED_CLASS(klass)       (G_TYPE_CHECK_CLASS_TYPE  ((klass), RECKLESS_FIXED_TYPE))
#define RECKLESS_FIXED_GET_CLASS(obj)        (G_TYPE_INSTANCE_GET_CLASS  ((obj), RECKLESS_FIXED_TYPE, RecklessFixedClass))

typedef struct _RecklessFixed      RecklessFixed;
typedef struct _RecklessFixedClass RecklessFixedClass;

struct _RecklessFixed
{
    GtkFixed container;
};

struct _RecklessFixedClass
{
    GtkFixedClass container_class;
};

GType reckless_fixed_get_type(void);
GtkWidget* reckless_fixed_new(void);

static void reckless_fixed_get_preferred_width(GtkWidget *widget, int *minimal, int *natural);
static void reckless_fixed_get_preferred_height(GtkWidget *widget, int *minimal, int *natural);

#endif /* __RECKLESS_FIXED_H__ */
```

*reckless_fixed.c*

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include "reckless_fixed.h"

G_DEFINE_TYPE( RecklessFixed, reckless_fixed, GTK_TYPE_FIXED )

static void reckless_fixed_class_init( RecklessFixedClass* klass ) {
    GtkWidgetClass *widget_class = GTK_WIDGET_CLASS(klass);
    widget_class->get_preferred_width = reckless_fixed_get_preferred_width;
    widget_class->get_preferred_height = reckless_fixed_get_preferred_height;
}
static void reckless_fixed_init( RecklessFixed* self ) {}

// here is where we are reckless about our content's size
static void reckless_fixed_get_preferred_width(GtkWidget *widget, int *minimal, int *natural) {
    *minimal = *natural = 1; 
}
//here too
static void reckless_fixed_get_preferred_height(GtkWidget *widget, int *minimal, int *natural) {
    *minimal = *natural = 1;
}
GtkWidget* reckless_fixed_new (void) {
  return g_object_new (RECKLESS_FIXED_TYPE, NULL);
}
```

Please pay attention to the GTK version - the example above is applicable to **GTK-3.0**. For <=2.0 the **::size-request** signal exists, by connecting and answering to which the same goal is achieved.

Besides I'd warn about this approach - do it **only for the cases where you're absolutely sure about what you are doing and why you need the content-independent window resize**, as this breaks the inbuilt GTK layout system.